# In Meteor when trying to access an attribute, I get TypeError: Cannot read property in the console. But the site is working

Tags: meteor

When trying to read an attribute, meteor gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'featuredImage' of undefined` error in the browser console. But it reads `featuredImage` and the site is working fine. How can I get rid of this error? Is it happening because my subscriptions are not yet ready? Is that's the case, how to fix it? (PS : Im using the flow router so I can't wait for subscriptions in the router)

My template code :

```
Template.About.helpers({
    page: () => {
        return findPage();
    },
    featuredImage: () => {
        var thisPage = findPage();
        return Images.findOne({
            "_id": thisPage.featuredImage
        });
    }
});

function findPage() {
    return Pages.findOne({
        slug: 'about'
    });
}
```

The router code :

```
FlowRouter.route('/about', {
    name: 'about',
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.register('page', Meteor.subscribe('pages', 'about'));
        this.register('image', Meteor.subscribe('images'));
    },
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {
            content: 'About'
        });
        setTitle('About Us');
    },
    fastRender: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription is probably not ready yet. FlowRouter provides a utility for dealing with this, your helpers should look like this:

```
Template.About.helpers({
    page: () => {
       // If you only need a specific subscription to be ready
       return FlowRouter.subsReady('page') && findPage() || null;
    },
    featuredImage: () => {
        // Ensure ALL subscriptions are ready
        if ( FlowRouter.subsReady() ) {
          var thisPage = findPage();
          return Images.findOne({
            "_id": thisPage.featuredImage // Probably should be thisPage.featuredImage._id
          });
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

However, for maximum performance, you should use `if (FlowRouter.subsReady('page') && Flowrouter.subsReady('image'))` rather than `FlowRouter.subsReady()` since if you have other pending subscriptions which are large, it will wait for those even though you don't need them.